# Is there a way to command during runtime to not to call a particular function (to comment it out) in C (Linux)?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, g++

I want to specify during run-time to ignore a function call for a function (which is of course defined) inside my executable. Please suggest some methodology for doing the same in C language on Linux.

Comment: You mention runtime, but then mention the compilers. Is this an existing executable, or something you're compiling? The main way that comes to mind for doing this is to parse the command-line parameters, and set a flag in your program based on that. Then wrap your function call in an `if`.

Comment: C is a compiled language, that means the program is compiled *once* and then the code is fixed in the executable. You might want to consider run-time checking (with e.g. command line arguments and `if` statements) to see if the function should be called or not.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, do you mean `#ifdef`?

Comment: Sorry, about putting it wrongly. I was looking for a command or a flag in linux which can be put in while running the executable to specify such requirement. eg. `./a.out -flag FUNCTION NAME`

Comment: It would be some access-control or copy-protection functionality you wish to deactivate?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best you can do is something like this:

```
// Filename mycode.c

int main()
{
  // ...
  #ifndef SOME_MACRO
  someFUnction();
  #endif

  //...

}


int someFUnction()
{

 // does something

}
```

To exclude the function call in main, you need to compile with

`gcc -DSOME_MACRO  mycode.c`

If you will compile simply as

`gcc mycode.c`

then the function call will be enabled.

Comment: Sorry, I had meant during execution. I mistakenly mentioned gcc and g++.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ignore function calls at runtime, you either call the function or you don't.

But let's assume for the sake of this answer that there exists a condition under which the function gets called and at least another condition under which the function is not called.

You can tell the program these conditions in several ways, for example per command-line, change of environment/file, and probably a long list more. For simplicity let's use the command-line and give the conditions in form of a argument to the executable. Additionally, because it is simple and short, use a signal.

File `optional_functions.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <dlfcn.h>

static void a(void)
{
  puts("Function \"a\" called");
}

static void b(void)
{
  puts("Function \"b\" called");
}

static void c(void)
{
  puts("Function \"c\" called (by signal SIGINT)");
}

#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

static void signal_handler(int signal_number)
{
  if (signal_number == SIGINT) {
    c();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  void *dynlib;
  void (*function_d) (void);
  char *dynlib_error;

  if (argc == 2) {
    if (argv[1][0] == 'a') {
      a();
    } else if (argv[1][0] == 'b') {
      b();
    } else if (argv[1][0] == 'd') {
      puts("External function \"d\" wanted, loading library");
      dynlib = dlopen("libfunctiond.so", RTLD_LAZY);
      if (dynlib == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed loading lib: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      *(void **) (&function_d) = dlsym(dynlib, "d");
      dynlib_error = dlerror();
      if (dynlib_error != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed calling function \"d\" fom lib: %s\n",
                dynlib_error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      (*function_d) ();

    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "A function named \"%c\" does not exist, bailing out\n",
              argv[1][0]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  } else {
    if (signal(SIGINT, signal_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
      fprintf(stderr, "signal catching failed, bailing out\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sleep(5);
    puts("Signal catching timed out, assuming no function wanted in the first place.");
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

File `functiond.h`

```
#ifndef FUNCTIOND_H
#define FUNCTIOND_H
void d(void);
#endif
```

File `functiond.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functiond.h"
void d(void)
{
  puts("Function \"d\" called and says hello from the library");
}
```

Compile as

```
clang -Weverything -fPIC  -c functiond.c
clang -shared -Wl,-soname,libfunctiond.so.1 -o libfunctiond.so.1.0   functiond.o
ln -sf libfunctiond.so.1.0 libfunctiond.so.1
ln -sf libfunctiond.so.1 libfunctiond.so
clang -Weverything -o optional_functions optional_functions.c example.c -ldl
```

Run it

```
$ ./optional_functions # waiting 5 seconds
Signal catching timed out, assuming no function wanted in the first place.
$ ./optional_functions # press CTRL+c in less than 5 seonds
^CFunction "c" called (by signal SIGINT)
$ ./optional_functions 1
A function named "1" does not exist, bailing out.
$ ./optional_functions a
Function "a" called
$ ./optional_functions b
Function "b" called
$ ./optional_functions d
External function "d" wanted, loading library
Failed loading lib: libfunctiond.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

That was expected. Either give `dlopen()` the complete path to the library or let the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` do the job:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./optional_functions d
External function "d" wanted, loading library
Function "d" called and says hello from the library
```

It is not the proper way to make, install and and use dynamic libraries, of course, but again: for the sake of simplicity…